# Given a set, I want to return a single object after excluding other objects in a django view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to return a single object to the template context so that I can reuse the object several times without haveing to do a query each time.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MessageCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        cohort = Cohort.objects.filter(members=self.request.user)
        context['cohort_member'] = cohort.members.exclude(members=self.request.user)
        return context
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'members'
```

So, I'm a little confused. Because I thought the attribute members WAS a part of cohort. If I iterate cohort in the template, I can get to the user.

So, I want that single user, not the entire set.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your models?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `cohort` is a queryset, not a model instance.  To get an actual model instance you have to evaluate the queryset, which you can do various ways - iterating over it, as you mention doing in the template, is one way to do so.  A queryset can contain more or less than one instance, of course.

That said, I'm a little puzzled about what you're trying to exclude and include.  Is `cohort_member` supposed to be a set of members of the cohort other than the request user?  If so, there are a couple of ways to do that depending on whether you need the cohort for anything other than that set of members in the template and whether the user to cohort relationship is many-to-many or many-to-one.  And, if many-to-many, whether you want all other users of all cohorts the user is a member of or whether you want them grouped separately.

Comment: I want to exclude the current user. request.user.

Comment: I can show you how to do that if you share the parts of your code that indicate what kind of relationship cohorts and users have - in particular, whether it's a `ManyToMany` relationship or not.  And if so, you'll need to say what you want to do in the case of multiple cohorts for the current user.